# nginx - proxy_pass with return 301 redirect

Tags: nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am building my nginx configuration with automated tools like [nginx-proxy on docker](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy). There they let me add a custom line inside the `location` directive.

Simply, I want `www.example.com` to be 301 redirected to `example.com`, or generally both `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` should be 301 redirected to `https://example.com`.

The automated configuration creation results as such:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<upstream>;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com;
    }
}
```

I notice that there are `proxy_pass` syntax before `return 301 ...`, and since its creation is automated, I don't think I can easily modify that (i.e. to make return 301 appear before the `proxy_pass` syntax.

From [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> `proxy_pass`
>
> Sets the protocol and address of a proxied server and an optional URI to which a location should be mapped.

So, nginx-wise question, since it said "sets", will the 301 redirect be done correcly, even if the redirect came after the `proxy_pass` syntax ?

Comment: The order of those two statements is unimportant - your configuration file contains two mutually exclusive statements. However, Nginx will evaluate the `return` statement in an earlier execution phase, so the `proxy_pass` statement should be completely ignored.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thankyou again for the detailed answer (comment)!

Answer (score 0):

From the comment by RichardSmith, it is said that the `return` syntax will be evaluated first and hence `proxy_pass` is completely ignored.